# What is the difference between conda uninstall and conda remove?

Tags: conda, uninstallation

It seems that both commands can be used to remove packages:

```
conda uninstall numpy
```

```
conda remove numpy
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference, they are the same command.

Check the `help` output of `conda uninstall`:

```
conda uninstall --help
usage: conda-script.py uninstall [-h] [-n ENVIRONMENT | -p PATH] [-c CHANNEL] [--use-local] [--override-channels]
                                 [--repodata-fn REPODATA_FNS] [--all] [--features] [--force-remove] [--no-pin] [-C]
                                 [-k] [--offline] [-d] [--json] [-q] [-v] [-y] [--dev]
                                 [package_name [package_name ...]]

Alias for conda remove.
[...]
```

Note the **Alias for conda remove.**